# C# Web Service Impersonation

Tags: c#, web-services

If I enable impersonation in a web service with identity="someID"... As web service is MTA application the impersonation that is applied may be applied to a worker thread and not the thread that actually call the method... I guess you might get an access denied error...Without problematically doing impersonation .. just by enabling it in webconfig .. what changes will i have to make to my function which does some clever stuff?

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="DomainName\UserName" 
                         password="ClearTextPassword" />
```

The `<identity>` element within Web.config supports optional user name and password attributes which allows you to configure a specific fixed identity for your Web service to impersonate. This is shown in the following configuration file fragment...
what else do i need to write?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses(); 
p.GetExccutiong();
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Can I ask: what was the painful bit in "verification"? Was this setting up an openid? If you have feedback on this, I'm sure the site owners would love to hear it.

Comment: i had to add "i g n o "verfi" re this" this to get through verfifcation ... It kept on asking to describe my problem... and i had to type image chars atleast for 5 times... i guess if there is a spam stuff a moderator can always delete it ...yes this is a opneid..

Comment: Have you seen an actual problem with identity flowing correctly? That's been around since .NET 1.0 so chances are they've fixed most of any bugs in it.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, the best way to configure the identity of a web-service is via the host - IIS, for example. In IIS, you can configure this via the app-pool identity ([like in this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630183/sspi-connection-in-net-2-0-web-service/630220#630220). No need for plain-text passwords, and no need for hacky code.