# How do I disable ALL .NET security policies?

Tags: .net, asp.net, interop, iis-6

I'm trying to replace a old homebrewed single threaded web server with a ASP.NET solution that will run on IIS. The old server does alot of weird stuff like access files outside it's path, do com calls, write to c: and much more. It does all of this from library writen in C++.

In the new application we want to use the same library so we will eventually have to figure out how to make the app secure. But for now I just want to get a prototype running on IIS so that we can prove that it will be a improvment over the existing solution.

The problem is that I'm getting security exception after security exception from .NET. I've got rid of some by doing:

```
caspol -machine -chggroup 1.5. FullTrust
caspol -s off
```

But I still can't run it. What I have to work with is:

- Windows 2003 Server
- IIS 6
- .NET 2.0

I can also add that everything works as expected on casini but we need to get it up on IIS to prove that it's worth investing time in doing the switch.

How can I disable all .NET security so that I can run the prototype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(some minor edits)

It sounds like the security problems you are hitting are *windows* security issues, not *.NET* policies. As long as it is **for prototype only**, you could run it as an admin. [Change the app-pool's identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630183/sspi-connection-in-net-2-0-web-service/630220#630220) to an administrative account (or yourself). And pray ;-p

For *real* work, you would create a non-administrative domain account with just the necessary permissions.

I imagine it works in the development web-server because it is running as *you*.

Comment: You are right it was the windows security I was hitting. Running as admin solved this issue but now I have several more (non security realted) to solve. Thank You.